# Plot de un Clustering

Tags: python, machine-learning, apache-spark, pyspark

Tengo un vector llamado `pca`, del cual descompongo sus valores los cuales llame `x` y `y` de la siguiente manera:

```
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
var = transformed.select('customer_id','pca')
def extract(row):
    return (row.customer_id, ) + tuple(row.pca.toArray().tolist())
var_a = var.rdd.map(extract).toDF(["customer_id"]) 
var_a = var_a.withColumnRenamed("_2","x")
var_a = var_a.withColumnRenamed("_3","y")
var_a.show()
```

Dándome como resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego separo x y y de la siguiente forma:

```
x = var_a.select("x")
y = var_a.select("y")
```

Esto con el fin de poder hacer un `ScatterPlot` de las dos varibles, mi intento fue como se muestra en el siguiente código. Cabe mencionar que la columna `prediction` a la que hago referencia lo único que me trae son  valores del 0 al 6, por ende los siete colores de asignación para diferenciar los `clusters`.

```
df = predictions_pca.select('prediction').toPandas()
colores=['red','green','blue','yellow','fuchsia','black','purple']
asignar=[]
for row in df:
    asignar.append(colores[int(row)])
        
plt.scatter(x, y, c=asignar, s=1)
plt.xlabel('Var_1')
plt.ylabel('Var_2')
plt.title('K-Means Clustering')
plt.show()
```

Si embargo, a pesar de esto me marca in error en el código. Alguien podría orientarme o decirme que estoy haciendo mal.

Adjunto la traza del error que me marca:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿ Que significa `me marca error en el código` ? ¿ Que mensaje de error ? ¿ En que línea ? Por favor, revisa [¿ Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta ?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Un saludo.

Comment: @Trauma, listo ya he adjuntado una imagen con el error que se me despliega.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente lo pude resolver. Lo que me faltaba era un `collect`  y castear las variables a `lista` de la siguiente forma:

```
x = list(var_a.select('x').collect())
y = list(var_a.select('y').collect())
```

Con practicaente el mismo codigo para hacer el Plot:

```
df = predictions_pca.toPandas()
colores=['red','green','blue','yellow','fuchsia','cyan','purple']
asignar=[]
for row in range (len(df)):
    asignar.append(colores[df['prediction'][row]])
plt.figure(figsize = (16, 9))    
plt.scatter(x, y, c=asignar)
plt.scatter(cent[:,0], cent[:,1],marker='*', c='black') # Marco centroides.
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.title('K-Means Clustering')
plt.show()
```

Obtuve la salida esperada:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que a alguien más le sea de ayuda ¡Saludos!